# How to align GridLayout in Android layout XML?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

I have a (3x2 = 3 col & 2 rows) GridLayout and I would like to add there in the first row image/icons and in to the second row some text:

```
<GridLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/gridLayout_2"
android:columnCount="3"
android:rowCount="2"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dim50dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_size"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/money_80"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_size"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/money_80"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/icon_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/icon_size"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/money_80"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:text="AAA"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:text="BBB"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:text="CCC"/>
</GridLayout>
```

Which then leads to this [image: screen]
whereas I would like to center all those gridItems as [image: this], especially with the text under the icon/image.

**Is that possible?**

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi imagine that those images ont he top, are different, corresponding to the text below. I just have not desinged it yet.

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi Ah ok, thank you. I get it. ! small question, is it possible to scale the images?

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi when you answer with your first answer I can makr it as closed ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better if you use only 3 TextViews (1 row), with a top compound drawable inside.

This will save you from having 3 useless ImageViews in your layout
You can use whichever image (or drawable) you want.
By doing so, I save a lot of useless Views, which helps for better performances.

I never considered wether the images are scalable or not (I use pre-scaled images), but I guess that they are fixed.